# FlexLib HAccordion - No Text in Flex 4.1

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I've searched hi and low for a way to get FlexLib's HAccordion to work in Flex 4.1. Has anyone been able to get it to work? I hear it worked in Flex 4.0 using embedded fonts, but the code provided in various posts claiming to have it working weren't successful in 4.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So... are you using an embeded font as the font-family for the HAccordin ?

If not that is for sure the problem because fonts that are not embeded do not support roation.

Comment: Hi TiMeister, sorry for not being more clear, but yes, I have embedded the fonts. Here is my code:


 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   [Embed(source='../fonts/Arial.ttf', fontWeight="bold", fontName='accordionHeader', mimeType='application/x-font', advancedAntiAliasing='true')] 
   private var font1:Class;
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>